# iWebKit Page Slider - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webkit

Anyone a Idear for a Pageslider for iWebKit so if i click on a link it change like nativ apps?

So the slide from page to page look like native? Maybe someone got something in javascript that is easy to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Wait for iwebkit6.

Or do it yourself!
Load the page with ajax, set it to the right of the current content and use css3 transitions to move everything to the left.